# How to Get Azure Id Token after successful login in asp .net core application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I can see `UserId` token in Formdata in response of signinodc API. How can I get that token in asp .net core application?

Below code has written for authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

In Configure method `app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();`

Comment: the code will be in the URL after Azure AD redirects to the endpoint your app is running

Comment: Can you please elaborate briefly ? i am using the url https://login.microsoftonline.com/{client_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44321%2Fsignin-oidc
&scope=openid
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910  for authentication

Comment: please read / follow the official article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration

Comment: i have already implemented  the same for authentication and authentication is working fine but unfortunately i dint find any code to get azure id token in asp.net core application. Can you please suggest me how will i retrieve the id token which i got it in developer tool

Comment: Any solution for this please?

Comment: Could you pls share your requirement for id token? After you integrate azure ad in your asp.net core web app, you've got the sign in feature and if you need to authorize, id token is not suitable as the saying `ID tokens should not be used for authorization purposes` in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens). @Suchismita

Comment: You can also refer to [this flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#protocol-diagram-access-token-acquisition), I'm afraid what you need is access token.

Answer (score -1):

You can use get `AccessToken` from the API by using below code

```
public  async  Task<JArray> GetApiDataAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var  client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var  scope = _configuration["CallApi:ScopeForAccessToken"];
        var  accessToken = await  _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { scope });
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Follow the steps using on the [blog](https://damienbod.com/2020/05/29/login-and-use-asp-net-core-api-with-azure-ad-auth-and-user-access-tokens/)

Check here for more reference of the [AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)